# R Markdown imprime en blanco las tablas hechas con kable()

Tags: rstudio, table, r-markdown

A raíz de que tuve que desinstalar y volver a instalar R y R studio en mi PC tengo problemas para ver las tablas hechas con la función kable() en R Markdown.

Cuando corro el chunk no me da ningún error con la construcción de la tabla, pero en el Notebook Output los elementos de la tabla aparecen en letra de color blanco a excepción de los títulos, y con el fondo blanco que aparece por defecto no puedo ver el contenido de la tabla a no ser que seleccione el texto con el cursor. Sin embargo, la tabla se muestra en el Viewer de forma correcta. Cuando hago knit a HTML, también aparece la tabla de forma correcta con todos los elementos visibles. El único problema es que en el mismo output del chunk no puedo visualizar correctamente tablas que, en el pasado, sí podía ver bien.

Esto me resulta problemático porque soy estudiante y necesito poder visualizar correctamente el output de mis tablas para poder seguir trabajando en mis entregas, ya que tengo que usar kable() sí o sí y resulta demasiado laborioso estar pendiente del Viewer o knit a HTML para poder ver si mi tabla está hecha correctamente.

Actualmente tengo R studio 1.2.5001 y R 3.6.1. Antes tenía la versión más reciente de R studio, pero no recuerdo cuál era la versión de R que tenía instalada, pero seguro que no estaba actualizada y no tenía ningún problema para el visualizado de las tablas en R Markdown.

Espero que podáis ayudarme con mi problema. Muchas gracias.

Edit:

Adjunto una captura de pantalla en que se ve la tabla como la presenta R Markdown y como se ve en el Viewer
[image: Tabla con el contenido en blanco en R Markdown]

Respecto al sistema operativo:

Edición Windows 10 Pro
Versión 1903
Instalado el 2/10/19
Versión del sistema operativo 18362.418

Adjunto el código, ya que siguen apareciéndome los contenidos de las tablas en blanco por defecto, incluso cuando la tabla es construida por alguien que no soy yo. Entiendo que, por defecto, debería verse el contenido en color negro sin tener que añadir código extra para el color del contenido, como sucedía antes.

```
table <- summaryBy(age + hours ~ sex + type, FUN = c(mean, sd, length), data = caregivers)
table <- table[, c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 4, 6, 8)]

table[,3:8] <- round(table[ ,3:8] ,2)

colnames(table) <- c("Gender", "Type", "M", "SD", "n", "M", "SD", "n")
table[2,1] = table[4,1] = NA

kable_styling(kable(table, align = "l") %>%
  kable_styling("striped") %>%
  add_header_above(c("" , " " , "Age" = 3, "Hours" = 3)))
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Me parece que tu problema es más de configuración que de programación. Por las dudas puedes leer [help/dont-ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Te sugiero que agregas a tu pregunta, el dato del sistema operativo y una captura de pantalla para entender como se ve la tabla que mencionas.

Comment: Es raro, habría que revisar el código del archivo .Rmd, para descartar alguna configuración particular de estilos. Una solución alternativa, sería probar configurara específicamente el color a usar, por ejemplo, agregando `table.attr = "style = \"color: black;\""` en la invocación de `kable()`